# In a Makefile, how can I begin processing a file before it has finished building?

Tags: make, streaming, parallelism

I'm using `make` to automate a project that generates lots of data, then processes it, with recipes roughly like this:

```
processed-data: data
    data-processing-program $^ > $@

data:
    output-data > $@
```

The `data` has its own recipe, because *various other targets process it too*.

The `output-data`-program runs for a while. Once it's done, the `data-processing-program` begins, and eventually produces `processed-data`:

> [image: data output, then processing]

That could clearly be faster, by running both in parallel, streaming `data` to the `data-processing-program` before the file is complete:

> [image: simultaneous output and processing]

How do I express such a relationship in a `Makefile`?

---

Options I've considered:

- I tried [using `--jobs`/`-j` to execute multiple recipes in parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel), but `make` still waits for any recipe to complete before executing its dependents.
- I observed that if I were doing this manually, I'd just write a pipeline:

  ```
  output-data | data-processing-program > processed-data
  ```

  That would process the data as soon as any of it is available.

  I toyed with a recipe to emulate that, by having the `data` recipe create a [named pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) instead of a file, and spawn a background process to write the data to it.  However, the data in the pipe can only be read once, making it impossible to process the same data with multiple recipes.

Comment: What you see is the intended behaviour: the `processed-data: data` rule says that `processed-data` depends on `data`.  Change that if you want to build the two in parallel.

Comment: @lcd047 How? Are you recommending to simply remove the `data` dependency from `processed-data` and run `make -j2 data processed-data`? Wouldn't that create a race condition where `processed-data` can fail if the `data` isn't present yet?

Comment: How would I know what's appropriate for what you're trying to do?  I'm just pointing out that what you have now doesn't stand a chance to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can have your cake and eat it too by using `tee` to save one copy of the output to disk, while feeding the other to `data-processing-program`:

```
output-data | tee data | data-processing-program > processed-data
```

This will leave a properly time-stamped copy of `data` for other targets in your makefile.

There are any number of ways to associate this pipeline with dependencies, so I'll let you choose whatever makes sense to you. (Unless you're still stuck, in which case follow up.) E.g., since the rule generates both `data` and `processed-data` I might just write:

```makefile
data processed-data:
    output-data | tee data | data-processing-program > processed-data
```

Comment: If I've correctly understood, that way, `data-processing-program` gets the `data` streamed, but all other recipes dependent on `data` still have to wait until it's done. (Even worse, they now have to wait until *both `data` and the `processed-data`* are finished.)

Comment: Well yeah, you only specified wanting to start early with one consumer. You could pipe it through several iterations of `tee`, I suppose. Is `data` the only input for the other processes?

Comment: ① As mentioned, "`data` has its own recipe, because various other targets process it too." Sorry if that was unclear. How would several iterations of `tee` help? ② The other processing steps might also require other files. All they have in common is that they require the `data`.

Comment: It wasn't clear that they need to start early too, is all. Extra `tee`'s could be used to redirect to other streams (think `/dev/stderr`), but I couldn't say exactly how OTOMH.